# does auto deduce that a type is a pointer?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, auto

I am unclear about the usage of auto in a function I am looking over.  Given a parameter defined like:

`someFunction(const unique_ptr<BSTNode<int>>& node, paramType param) {`

the body of the function establishes a local variable like this:

`auto *localNode = node.get();`

My understanding of auto is that it deduces the type of what is assigned to it at compile time.  The docs state that `unique_ptr::get()` returns a pointer to the object that it manages.  Given that fact, why is it necessary to add `*` to the variable declaration?

Answer (score 6):

Using a `*` to deduce a pointer is unnecessary, but may be desirable.  If the code is later changed such that the initializer no longer returns a pointer, the `*` will cause auto deduction to fail.  If the code that uses this variable is designed with a pointer in mind, this may be a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it necessary to add `*` to the variable declaration?

It's not. The benefit is that it makes it exceedingly obvious to the reader that `localNode` is a pointer.

Comment: but if auto already deduces the type to a pointer than would adding an additional * not result in a ** type?

Comment: @user5797668 No, `auto` doesn't mean "the type of the initializer"; it means roughly "whatever type that is needed to make the whole thing's type match the type of the initializer".